# Testing with Hibernate: Object dependence chain on persistence

Tags: java, unit-testing, hibernate, junit, jmock

I am preparing unit tests for DAO layer which interacts with entity objects for persistence in to database.

Technology
Hibernate
Java 1.6
JUnit

Suppose i want to create test method addEntityA()

for doing so i create EntityA object. Now problem is EntityA is child of EntityB. So i must specify reference of EntityB in EntityA. EntityA will be persisted in database only if EntityB is persisted first. So thus to test persistnece of EntityA i will have test persistence of EntityB. this way it can lead to chain of entities which must be persisted before actual persistence of EntityA for testing. One may argue that i should give reference of EntityB object which is already persisted. But problem is that i don't want to make test cases dependent upon test in database rather than test data. Some how i resembles with what JMock solves but not sure how and if Jmock can be useful here?

Please let me know if problem is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your actual question is, but imo the best approach for testing Hibernate/JPA functionality is to use a in memory database and a decent test harness. With test harness I mean a base class for your persistence related classes which will create and drop your in memory database per test (maybe just per test class). The test harness should also provide access to the entity manager or session you are using during testing.
If you using filtering for your configuration files you can use properties to switch databases in order to test against "real" databases as well.
Last but not least, if your test of EntityA needs an EntityB you will need to create EntityB in the test setup or the test itself.
Have a look at the test harness of Hibernate Core to get an idea how testing is done there.

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem into two. Have your production code depend on a clean interface which can be mocked as you need. And then implement that interface with a layer that talks to the database. Test that layer with an instance of the real database since Hibernate failures are more often to do with the mappings than the code. Look for "Ports and Adapters Architecture" for more ideas.